# Android circle and rounded background

Tags: android, android-background

I need to implement widget, that has a background as shown on picture - circle if one digit, rounded rect, if two digits. It should have an ability of dynamically change. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: so write your custom `View`

Comment: @Anton Kizema : I guess you just need to define background of this view as `drawable` with `shape` attribute as `ring`.

Comment: you need to create custom style

Answer (score 1):

For the rounded rectangle add
 This xml to your drawable folder and set it as a background to the view you want

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid

    android:color="your own color" /> 

<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
    android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

For the circle add this xml in drawable folder

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >
<solid 
    android:color="your own color"

<size 
    android:width="4dp"
    android:height="4dp"/>
```

**change the height, width,corner radius sizes to your liking**

Answer (score 1):

To create background as in question above, You need to create custom shape and apply as background of `TextView`.

**ring.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/selectable_kachel_shape">
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="2"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <!--<solid android:color="#ff00ffff"/>-->
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:type="sweep"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:innerRadius="0dp"
               android:shape="ring"
               android:thicknessRatio="2.2"
               android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Please use this `ring.xml` as background of `TextView` as below :

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_pending_count"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ring"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Thanks.